# KNIME persistent tables

Tags: database, knime

I am new to KNIME and would like to know if this platform supports persistent tables or focuses only on extracting data from different data sources and not on storing them permanently?
Is there a way to store data completely within KNIME and not use databases? If so, is this a logical solution? Can KNIME completly replace database?

Answer (score 1):

Saving a KNIME workflow will save the status of each node in the workflow, including the data at the node's output ports, but that's not a durable method of persisting data - you should think of it as more of a cache function to speed up execution of a workflow by not recalculating data that hasn't changed. If you were to reset a node or change its configuration, its stored data would be lost.

If you want to keep the data that you operate on with a KNIME workflow you should use the file or database nodes to load and save it in a suitable way. If storing data in files doesn't meet your needs, but you don't need multi-user access, I might look at an SQLite database which is fairly easy to set up.